# How to add a class to a link in text editor

Tags: widgets, text

The editors of my web are absolute noobs :)
They don't now anything about CSS an HTML. Therefore I have a question:

Some links should get a class for styling them as a nice button. Is it possible to enhance the WP text widget link section by adding a simple checkbox "Link is a super-special button"? And when checked the button a class is added to the a tag?

[image]

Comment: Requests for plugin recommendations are specifically off topic here at WordPress development. See this link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Ok, I wil change my request...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use third party free WordPress plugin "**Extend Link**". You can activate this plugin and add extend link as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

Now when you click on "Extend Link", you will see the popup similar to default link popup but with an additional option to add IDs, Class and Rel.

[image]

https://wordpress.org/plugins/extend-link/

Please let me know if this helps..!!

Comment: Thx, this plugin works fine for me :)

Comment: Glad...That helped...!! 
Can you please mark answer so that it could help other developers here. Thanks.